# Snap no instala correctamente los programas en Debian

Tags: bash, debian

Snap no puede instalar programas en Huayra 5.0 (Debian 10).

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
sudo snap install snap-store
```

no encuentro la tienda en el menú ni en la barra de búsqueda, y al intentar ejecutar `sudo snap-store` me dice:

```
bash: snap-store: orden no encontrada
```

Intente ejecutar también otras aplicaciones pero lo mismo.
si alguien puede ayudarme le agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Hola El Papu, antes de la ordenes que diste usaste **sudo apt update**?.

Comment: si, lo hice. tal cual como en los tutoriales de youtube